# Apple Pay shipping issue: onshippingmethodselected overriding onshippingcontactselected

Tags: javascript, applepay

Am writing a integration for applepay and am having an issue with the international shipping methods.

When I change the shipping address (call onshippingcontactselected) the methods and total update as they should.

However when I do so onshippingmethodselected is immediately called and switches the total back.  You can briefly see the total displaying correctly before it changes back.

Here's what I've got:

```
        session.onshippingmethodselected = function(event) {
            log('starting session.onshippingmethodselected', event.shippingMethod);

            var status = ApplePaySession.STATUS_SUCCESS;
            var newLineItems = [{ label: 'Sub Total', amount: amount }, {label: event.shippingMethod['title'], amount: event.shippingMethod['amount'] }];
            var newTotal = {label: 'Total', amount: Number(amount) + Number(event.shippingMethod['amount'])};
            session.completeShippingMethodSelection(status, newTotal, newLineItems);
        }


        session.onshippingcontactselected = function(event) {
            log('starting session.onshippingcontactselected', event.shippingContact);

            var newShippingMethods = shipping[event.shippingContact.countryCode];
            var status = ApplePaySession.STATUS_SUCCESS;
            var newLineItems = [{ label: 'Sub Total', amount: amount }, {label: newShippingMethods[0]['title'], amount: newShippingMethods[0]['amount']}];
            var newTotal = {label: 'Total', amount: Number(amount) + Number(newShippingMethods[0]['amount'])};
            session.completeShippingContactSelection(status, newShippingMethods, newTotal, newLineItems);
        };
```

I think I need a way to suppress onshippingmethodselected until it is actually selected by the user or find a way to update the shipping details it uses, haven't managed to do either successfully so any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Jimi

I have tried setting the shipping method as a global variable and updating it in  onshippingcontactselected then calling it from onshippingmethodselected.
Although the global variable seems to be updating correctly, it is still returning the old shipping method when called.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Am running into the same issue where onshippingmethodselected is overriding the total that is being populated on contact selected.